# Why is this IronPython module path not visible?

Tags: module, location, ironpython

I am trying to find the location of a IronPython module on my PC. According to this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
print(ET.__file__)
```

...the path to the module is

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py'
```

However when I look up this path there is no 'xml' in 'Lib'

Why could this be?

Comment: You are using IronPython, not the regular CPython binary. IronPython is almost certainly materially different in how it packages the standard library.

Comment: In the meantime, you can find those modules in the IronPython GitHub repository. E.g. [the `xml\etree\` folder for IronPython v2.7.9](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/tree/ipy-2.7.9/Src/StdLib/Lib/xml/etree); adjust the tag to match your exact version.

Comment: And finally, I suspect that the source code is instead imported from a .zip file; does your `sys.path` list have any entries that end in `python27.zip` perhaps? Then that zip file is probably where the compiled version of the module was loaded from, and that object still records the original location of the `.py` source file.